# How to check folder permission in Java using apache commons net3.3

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-commons

I kinda stuck in a problem. I am using java and apache commons net3.3 for the FTPconnection. I want to transfer the folders from my local to the remote machine. I have completed everything, but Before transfering the folders I wanted to check the remote folder permission. 
I have used following function,

```
public boolean getPermission(String path) throws IOException
     {
         FTPFile myfile = ftpClient.listDirectories(path)[0];
         if (myfile.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.WRITE_PERMISSION)){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
```

But unfortunately i got error, I even tried using `FTPFile myfile = ftpClient.listFiless(path)[0];` But that fails either. To be specific, after some time I get following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at lib.FtpConnection.getPermission(FtpConnection.java:53)
    at app.Run.main(Run.java:28)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Of course you get an error, your code assumes there is exactly one file/directory, but clearly the list methods are returning empty arrays so there is no file/directory to list. Quite possibly the methods are already not returning files/directories for which you have no access.

Comment: then is there a solution for it